# Notification Action Button Pending Intent is not working

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, localnotification

I am adding two action button on the local notification. I have set pending intent to each action with some parameter and calling broadcast receiver. On broadcast receiver's onReceive method when I try to get the intent.getStringExtra() return null every time. I know it's an easy question but I am missing something I am unable to find it. Sorry for this.

Adding Action Button:

```
Intent takenIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationReceiver.class);
        takenIntent.setAction(Constants.TAKEN);
        Toast.makeText(context,time,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        takenIntent.putExtra(Constants.TIME,time);
        Log.e(Constants.TIME,time);


        PendingIntent takenPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, takenIntent, 0);

        Intent notTakenIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationReceiver.class);
        notTakenIntent.putExtra(Constants.TIME,time);
        notTakenIntent.setAction(Constants.TAKEN);

        PendingIntent notTakenIntentPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, notTakenIntent, 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, id)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(AppUtils.get12HrsDate(time))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setGroupSummary(true)
                .setGroup(GROUP_KEY)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setChannelId(id)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_drug_profile,context.getString(R.string.taken), takenPendingIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_drug_profile,context.getString(R.string.not_taken), notTakenIntentPendingIntent);
```

NotificationReceiver Broadcast:

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = NotificationReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if(intent != null){
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if(action != null){
                // always return null
                String time = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.TIME);
                if(action.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.TAKEN)){
                    Toast.makeText(context,action + " " + time,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e(TAG,action);
                }else if(action.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.NOT_TAKEN)){
                    Toast.makeText(context,action + " " + time,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e(TAG,action);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".receiver.NotificationReceiver" />
```

I have put a debugger and check while doing putExtra time value is not null.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding the issue correctly, but you're using `Constants.TAKEN` as the action for both `Intent`s. It seems like the second one should be using `Constants.NOT_TAKEN`. Since both `Intent`s currently target the same class, and have the same action, they are "filter-equal", and the same `PendingIntent` will be used for both, but the extras will not change, as you've passed `0` for the last argument. You'll want to fix the second action usage, and change that last argument to `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`, if you plan to call that code repeatedly to update `time`.